# Image colors composition using R

Tags: r, image, image-processing, colors, rgb

I'm trying to obtain the percentage of each color which compose a given picture.
I get the RGB matrix using this code:

```
library(jpeg)
img <- readJPEG("C:/Users/Pictures/img.jpg")
dim(img)
#145 371   3
img<-img*255
#this operation is necessary to obtain an RBG scale
```

At this step I'm not sure which is the right way to go ahead. Anyway, I would like to obtain someting like this:

```
Count    RGB vector

200614   (255,255,255) 

4758     (253,253,218) 

4312     (250,250,229) 

1821     (235,237,242) 

1776     (212,214,226)

...
```

and then I can calculate the percentage of each color.
Lastly I'll try to associate a label to each RGB vector.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can easily count colors with `table` after converting the pixel array to #rrggbb values with `as.raster` (note that you don't need to scale the values by multiplying them by 255). Individual color components from hex color strings can be obtained by `col2rgb`.

```
library(jpeg)
img <- readJPEG("C:/Users/Pictures/img.jpg")

# Convert the 3D array to a matrix of #rrggbb values
img <- as.raster(img)

# Create a count table
tab <- table(img)

# Convert to a data.frame
tab <- data.frame(Color = names(tab), Count = as.integer(tab))

# Extract red/green/blue values
RGB <- t(col2rgb(tab$Color))
tab <- cbind(tab, RGB)

# Preview
head(tab)
```

Comment: It worked, many thanks! Do you know if there is an already implemented function that can help me to give a label to each color found? I guess it is necessary to group some RBG vectors in order to obtain a reasonable number of labels.

Comment: Could you maybe clarify what exactly do you mean by these labels? Are the supposed to be color names corresponding to `colors()`?

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I mean, I would like to add another column to tab which shows the name of the color for eg. :

    Color Count red green blue name
1 #000000 11600   0     0    0   white
2 #00C25F     1   0   194   95   black
3 #00C34B    81   0   195   75  yellow
4 #00C454     1   0   196   84 ...
5 #00C45E     1   0   196   94 ...
6 #00C764     1   0   199  100 ...

Do you think is it possible?

Many Tnx

Comment: I posted another question, so I can give you another score. Tnx